# duplicated content with load content while scrolling down using jquery, php

Tags: php, jquery, scroll

i have a code that when I scroll down my page it will load further contents from the database, but my problem is when I scroll too fast, the contents loaded from the database duplicates, if I use this code and the outcome comes to that, it will be troublesome for my users,

here is the code:

```
<?php
include('../connection.php');

$action = @$_POST['action'];
$boxid = @$_POST['boxid'];

if($action <> "get")
{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scroll.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function last_msg_funtion() 
        { 

           var boxid=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
           var action = "get";
            $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
            $.post("loader.php", { boxid: boxid, action: action }, function(data){
                if (data != "") {
                $(".message_box:last").after(data);         
                }
                $('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
            });
        };  

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
               last_msg_funtion();
            }
        }); 

    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div align="center">

<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcements ORDER BY announce_id DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msgID= $row['announce_id'];
        $msg= $row['content'];
        $posted= $row['postedby'];
?>
<div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>"  align="left" class="message_box" >
<span class="number"><?php echo $posted; ?></span><?php echo "<b>".$msgID."</b>"; echo $msg; ?> 
</div>

<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>

<div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
else
{

$last_msg_id=$boxid;
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcements WHERE announce_id < '$boxid' ORDER BY announce_id DESC LIMIT 5");
 $last_msg_id="";

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msgID= $row['announce_id'];
        $msg= $row['content'];
        $posted= $row['postedby'];
        ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>"  align="left" class="message_box" >
<span class="number"><?php echo $posted; ?></span><?php echo "<b>".$msgID."</b>"; echo $msg; ?> 
</div>
<?php
}
mysql_close();


        }
        ?>
```

thanks in advanced! I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: make sure the data is loaded with complete method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. it may solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var boxid; // declare global
    function last_msg_funtion() 
    { 

   if(boxid==$(".message_box:last").attr("id")) return false;  // check with previous id

       boxid=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
       var action = "get";
        $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
        $.post("loader.php", { boxid: boxid, action: action }, function(data){
            if (data != "") {
            $(".message_box:last").after(data);         
            }
            $('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
        });
    };  

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           last_msg_funtion();
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: thanks @MMK ! you are a life saver! :) I'll try to analyze what you did with the code, or you just declared the boxid to global and that does it?

Comment: yes. we need to declare the boxid as global and check with boxid equal to last message box id equal means we need stop/return the function(because during ajax load they get previous msg id when scroll and that time global value also contain same id.) .

Answer (score 0):

well try this code... might just work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        function last_msg_funtion() 
        { 

           var boxid=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
           var action = "get";
            $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
            $.post("loader.php", { boxid: boxid, action: action }, function(data){
                if (data != "") {
                $(".message_box:last").after(data);         
                }
                $('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
            }).complete(function() { return true; });
        };  

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
               if(!last_msg_funtion()){
                   return false;
               }
            }
        }); 

    });
```

**Edit:** I changed exit, to return false... cause exit may break jquery.. not sure though test both whatever fits ur shoes ;)... Perhaps while would be better use instead of if... oh well

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, I want to know specifically what caused the duplicating data content if I scroll too fast or hold the Page Down key until I get to the very bottom of it, the content still duplicates, I tried your code but its still the same, and what do you mean that the data should be loaded using complete method api.jquery.com/jQuery.post